# Spark dataset agg method

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, databricks

I am working on creating some analytical data set using Spark and dataSet API. I got to part where I'm calcuating some variables and it looks something like this:

```
CntDstCdrs1.groupByKey(x => (x.bs_recordid, x.bs_utcdate)).agg(
   count(when(($"bc_sub_org_id" === lit(500) && $"bc_utcdate" >= $"day_1" && $"bc_utcdate" <= $"bs_utcdate") , $"bc_phonenum")).as[Long].name("count_phone_1day"),
   count(when(($"bc_sub_org_id" === lit(500) && $"bc_utcdate" >= $"day_3" && $"bc_utcdate" <= $"bs_utcdate") , $"bc_phonenum")).as[Long].name("count_phone_3day_cust"),
   count(when(($"bc_sub_org_id" === lit(500) && $"bc_utcdate" >= $"day_5" && $"bc_utcdate" <= $"bs_utcdate") , $"bc_phonenum")).as[Long].name("count_phone_5day_cust"),
   count(when(($"bc_sub_org_id" === lit(500) && $"bc_utcdate" >= $"day_7" && $"bc_utcdate" <= $"bs_utcdate") , $"bc_phonenum")).as[Long].name("count_phone_7day_cust")
  ).show()
```

This code works fine, but when I try to add one more count for variable "count_phone_30day" I get a error.."method overloaded..."
This means that agg method signature on dataSet takes maximum 4 Column expressions?
Anyway if this approach isn't best practice for calculating huge number of variables, then which one would be? I have count, count distinct, sum etc. variables.

KR,
Stefan

Comment: The `method overloaded` error is probably caused by something else, as `agg` on `Dataset` can take way more than 4 aggregate functions over `when` conditions.

Comment: @LeoC it can, but in relational `groupBy`, the Key-Value `groupByKey` has other implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dataset.groupByKey` returns [`KeyValueGroupedDataset`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset).

This class has no `agg` with varargs - you can provide only 4 columns as arguments